# Hide Developer Option in Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

How can I hide `Developer Option` in Samsung Galaxy S4.?

I surfed a lot but did not find any solution for this.
I found a link saying

> Re-Hide Developer Options:
>
> - go to your apps (menu -settings - apps, or menu - manage apps)
> - Under "All," scroll down until you find "Settings"
> - Tap on settings and then clear data/cache
> - This will NOT reset any settings, it will simply remove Developer options from the Settings menu

but it is also not working.

I had even reset my device still Developer Option is not hidden.

Is there any other way to hide Developer Option?

Comment: Any specific reason to close this question.? or this question has very simple answer...??????

Comment: Clearing data for Settings did it for me

Comment: @Aarun in setting only one option Clear Cache is enable else all are disable.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution which i found to this question is to **Factory Data Reset** device.

To Reset your device

1. From your home screen press the apps icon in the lower right corner.
2. Find and press the settings icon.
3. In the upper end of the screen press the accounts tab.
4. in the bottom of the next screen press the Backup and reset button.
5. Uncheck **Automatic restore**
6. Uncheck **Back up my data**
7. Press the factory data reset.
8. Read the info on your cell phone screen and hit Reset device.
9. Device will be restarted and your **Developer Option will be hidden**. :)

Comment: does this affect any data, installs already on the machine? tks

Comment: @HattrickNZ it will delete all your device data and reset all settings

Answer (score 0):

Open the "App manager" and check if the "Download-Manager" has been disabled.